# Change Column Dynamically inside a Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am executing a DB2 query which fetches multiple rows in excel.

I am trying to print all DB2 rows on different columns.

This is my current code:

```css
strSql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONTRACT='ABC';"
    
Set rst = conn.Execute(strSql)
    
Dim fldCount As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
    
fldCount = rst.Fields.Count
    
Do While rst.EOF = False
  For iCol = 1 To fldCount
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCol).Value = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name & ":" &      rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Value
  Next
        
  rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

But with this, all my records are getting overlapped over each other and hence only the last row is getting printed.

Is there any way to change the column when I read the next recordset ?

Comment: How do you mean "next recordset" your code is only opening 1 recordset, also it looks like you're adding each field and it's value to each row, not column???

Comment: I am using rst.MoveNext to loop through the recordsets. For the first loop, my entire DB2 columns are getting printed in column "A". I want to change column for next DB2 row when I move to next Recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
xx = 1
Do While rst.EOF = False
For iCol = 1 To fldCount
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCol, xx).Value = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name & ":" & rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Value
  Next
rst.MoveNext
xx = xx + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Yeah. It does. Thanks.